# Advanced Custom Fields and Commas in Numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) on my WordPress website and am trying to add a comma every 3rd place (1,000) instead of (1000) using PHP. I am utilizing the code below but when I save it the website breaks (critical error). I suspect this is my own error (novice) and hope someone can help me find out what I'm doing incorrectly or what I could try.

`

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=number_of_supporters', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format($value);
  return $value;
}
```

`

The website URL is https://coregiving.org and it leverages the Oxygen builder (if it's relevant).

Thank you!

-I was expecting the code I added to my website would add a comma delimiter-

[image]

Comment: no error on your website what error you are seeing

Comment: I just updated the original post with the output of the error message. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Either **Code Snippets** and **WPCode – Insert Headers and Footers** are conflicting or you have added the same code in both plugin's code snippets options. Also, I will suggest you give a function a good unique name using prefixes and meaningful definitions. e.g `fix_number` -> `vh_acf_format_number_value`

Comment: @VijayHardaha - That was it! Thank you! The plugin was creating a conflict. I sincerely appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ACF field type is `number`, ACF is going to return the raw number. Rather than trying to filter the value, you could instead use the number format function in the template where you are going to display it. Something like this:

```
echo number_format( get_field( 'number_of_supporters' ) );
```